# Integration proof without using primitive function

Tags: integration

I'm wondering how I can prove that this integral is divergent without using the primitive function? 
$$
\int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, dx
$$

Comment: Does "primitive function" mean the antiderivative $\ln$?

Comment: By change of variables this is equivalent to the divergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y} dy$, which is bounded from below by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} =\infty$.

Comment: @mvw Yes. Even Spivak uses primitive function in this sense.

Comment: Yes, the antiderivate :-) @mvw

Answer (score 4):

For $m\ge 1$, we have
$$\int_{1/(m+1)}^{1/m}\frac1x\,\mathrm dx\ge\int_{1/(m+1)}^{1/m}m\,\mathrm dx =\frac1{m+1}$$
hence 
$$\int_{1/(m+1)}^{1}\frac1x\,\mathrm dx\ge\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{k+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

By primitve, I take it that you mean antiderivative. Consider $ 2^n \leq 1/x\ \text{ for all }\ x\in(2^{-(n+1)}, 2^{-n}].$ Therefore
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\, dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}} \frac{1}{x}\, dx \geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}} 2^n\, dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}$$
which clearly diverges.